# Different results from polar and cartesian forms of a function?

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to write up and study the given function:

[image]

by the following Mathematica input (with N=5 and not infinity)

```
u[r_, phi_] := 
Piecewise[{{An*BesselJ[1.5 r, 5]*Exp[I 5 phi], 
0 < r < 1/2}, {(Bn*BesselJ[3 r, 5] + Cn*BesselY[3 r, 5])*
Exp[I 5 phi], 1/2 < r < 1}, {Dn*HankelH1[r, 5]*Exp[I 5 phi], 
r > 1}}]
```

But something is not correct here. If I convert it to Cartesian form by:

```
TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
 u[r, phi], {r, phi} -> {x, y}]
```

I obtain the following:

[image]

The I make the plots. Here is were the problem is identified. One of the two forms above, Cartesian or radial are wrong.

The first plot is the radial plot. When I plot u in Polar form I get this image (within the interval -1,1 , -1,1):

[image]

However, when I plot the Transformed form on the same interval, I get a completely different plot:

[image]

Clearly they are not the same, and they should.

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong with these plots. Your plot with using `r, phi` is not really polar. For polar plot we can use `PolarPlot[]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev But Polar plot does not plot in 3D, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean that functions plotting in 3D in polar coordinate and  in cartesian coordinates look different and therefore nothing wrong with your plots.

Comment: I think you might have to think a bit about what you are "really" doing when you "plot `u` in polar form" in the first example. There, Mathematica is taking `r` to be along one axis and `phi` to be along the other—it doesn't know that they are "supposed" to be radius and angle, if that makes sense. In the second, it takes the `x` parameter to be one axis and `y` to be the other. does that make sense?

Comment: Taking the polar form, I see that it requires different plotting way. But which?